# autocomplete search with sphinx

Tags: autocomplete, sphinx

I am looking for a very fast autocomplete solution for displaying results in mobile apps. I am using sphinx as full text index solution, but I thing if sphinx is the best one solution for autocomplete search, because after the index is searched, then I need to ask mysql for the results. Is there better and faster solution?

Comment: I need some clarity around the question. Do you mean auto suggest functionality where the user types and the system suggests terms, or do you mean wildcard searching where the user can type "micro*" and the system will bring back everything that starts with "micro"?

Comment: Hi Imraan, yes it is simmilar. But not only wordst with starts with. I need words with include as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can use string attributes, to store the actual text.

Then you don't need to go back to the database at all. Can just query sphinx. Sphinx stores attributes in memory; so doesn't slow the actual sphinx query searching down noticeably.

Sphinx works well for autocomplete in my experience.

Comment: Hi Barry, how to make this. I have searched so much for this. Can you show me an example how to store keywords in the index and by request to get the keywords back, without to need to ask mysql again by id?

Comment: really its nothing more than defining the column as a string attribute http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-sql-attr-string (or both a string attribute and a full-text field) - reindex your index, and you will get the data in the resultset. try print_r() if you dont know what the result looks like

Answer (score 1):

Sphinx supports wildcard searching. Have a look at the parameter "enable_star". If you set it to 1 and restart sphinx, you should be able to search using wildcards.

Check it out in the Sphinx [docs](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/2.0.4/conf-enable-star.html).

To find matches where any word contains "micro", the search term needs to be "*micro*".

Comment: Hi, yes I have try the enable star, but there is one problem - the exact match. I have in my configuration: min_word_len = 3 min_prefix_len = 1 enable_star = 1 and when I use '^'.$query.'*' for the query, then it works, but there is not the exact match in the result. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running sphinx 2.0.2 or greater:

```
index_exact_words = 1
```